# OrderByDescending by count of items via Lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, sql-order-by

I have type MyClass :

```
 MyClass
{
 public string Name { get;set; }
 public string LastName { get;set; }
}
```

and also i got my collection:

```
List<MyClass> _Lst = new List<MyClass>();
```

where i add some items like this:
UPD :

```
_Lst.Add(new MyClass{Name = "Petya" , LastName = "sergeevi4"};
_Lst.Add(new MyClass{Name = "Vasya" , LastName = "petrovi4"};
_Lst.Add(new MyClass{Name = "Igori" , LastName = "alibertovi4"};
_Lst.Add(new MyClass{Name = "Vasya" , LastName = "iakubovi4"};
_Lst.Add(new MyClass{Name = "Vasya" , LastName = "ianukovi4"};
```

So how i can sort(Descending) my collection via Lambda expressions to get something like this :

```
_Lst[0] = Name = "Vasya" , LastName = "iakubovi4"; //Where [n] - just index of mylist;
_Lst[1] = Name = "Vasya" , LastName = "petrovi4";
_Lst[2] = Name = "Vasya" , LastName = "ianukovi4";
_Lst[3] = Name = "Petya" , LastName = "sergeevi4";
_Lst[4] = Name = "Igori" , LastName = "alibertovi4";
```

At current moment i'm doing something like this :

```
var NewList = _Lst.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name.Count());
```

but,doesnt work properly.

Comment: Could you elaborate how it does not work properly? What is your expected behaviour? Do you see exceptions?

Comment: @Gábor Bakos No exceptions,but doesnt sort properly.

Comment: What does 'doesn't sort properly' mean?  In your question, for example, all names are the same length so it isn't clear what you'd expect the resulting order to be if that's what you're sorting on.

Comment: @CharlesMager i update my question. See how i'm added now values.

Comment: @VetaLio ah, ok - the answers below will help.  You wanted to sort with the most common names, your current code sorts by the *length* of the name (which is 5 in all cases).

Comment: @CharlesMager ok,now i'm understand why my sort wasn't good :). Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GroupBy` method suits your requirement perfectly.  A group is a collection with a key (in this case, a name).  You can order the grouping and then flatten out your collection using `SelectMany`:

```
var newList = _Lst.GroupBy(m => m.Name)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .ToList();
```

One piece of advice: it's better to use `ToArray()` than `ToList()`, as the resulting collection is immutable, and can't be modified after the fact, causing tricky bugs elsewhere in your code.

**BONUS:**

Once you've ordered by first name matches, you may want to order alphabetically by surname.  Again, this is easy because each group is a collection.  You can add a `Select` to your chain to achieve this:

```
var newList = _Lst.GroupBy(m => m.Name)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(m => m.LastName))
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Though it makes it more difficult, you can still replace every single item in the array so it's not immutable.

Comment: Good point.  Perhaps "less mutable" would be a better description.

Answer (score 1):

```
 List<MyClass> _Lst = new List<MyClass>();
 _Lst.Add(new MyClass { Name = "Vasya", LastName = "iakubovi4" });
 _Lst.Add(new MyClass { Name = "Vasya", LastName = "petrovi4" });
 _Lst.Add(new MyClass { Name = "Vasya", LastName = "ianukovi4" });
 _Lst.Add(new MyClass { Name = "Petya", LastName = "sergeevi4" });
 _Lst.Add(new MyClass { Name = "Igori", LastName = "alibertovi4" });

 var result = _Lst.GroupBy(m => m.Name).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: This gives a list of groups rather than a list of `MyClass` items.  How would you flatten this list?

Answer (score -1):

Just change your code as,

```
var NewList = _Lst.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name);
```

Comment: This snippet will sort by letter of my item.Name,but i need to sort by count of item.Names;

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: It's in the title: order by count of items.  In this case, the number of matching names.